# How can I set my weblogic's deployment mode to nostage?

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, weblogic, staging

My problem is that after every code change I have to build and deploy my Java web application (or at least some parts of it), which takes too much time.

**JRebel** would do the trick, but my company doesn't have a license for it. 
I heard that weblogic's **nostage mode** can save some time, but how can I configure it? 
I've changed my **Managed Server**'s staging mode in the Admin Console, but how can I provide the path to my `.wars`? Or how can I get this thing work?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I'm pretty new to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You now configured the default staging mode for new deployments, it would probably be easier to just change this during the individual deployments. If you are using the admin console to deploy it is the section called "Source accessibility".

Basically, in nostage / "I will make the deployment accessible" you tell WebLogic where to find your deployment by passing it a file location - which should be accessible for every targeted server. In the default staging mode (aptly called "stage"), you tell the admin server where to find the files and the admin server copies your files to the managed servers.

Unless your limits are in your bandwidth, I don't think this will save you any time during deployments.

Comment: Can you suggest any other workaround for this problem?

Comment: Have you considered WLS fastswap? WebLogic supports swapping out class files in exploded JAR / EARs under certain conditions - see https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/DEPGD/deployunits.htm#DEPGD153 - so you can skip compiling the archive and redeploy steps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it!